# How to lift more specific group specs?

Tags: clojure, pallet

this is a pallet (https://github.com/pallet) question. At the moment I try to use more specific group specs for my lift operations.
I try to lift just one specific node (e.g. a new one) in my group:

```
(api/lift 
    {jira-group #{meissa-jira-large}} 
    :user my-user
    :compute provider
    :phase [:init])
```

as described here: http://palletops.com/pallet/api/0.8/pallet.api.html#var-lift

But unfortunately I get

```
"group-spec error: Map did not contain expected path [:group-name]."
```

The more unspecific group spec is working fine:

```
(api/lift 
    jira-group
    :user my-user
    :compute provider
    :phase [:init])
```

Any idea, what I'm doing wrong?

Best regards,
Michael

PS: jira-group is defined as follows:

```
(def ^:dynamic jira-group
  (api/group-spec
    "jira-group"
    :extends [(config/with-config meissa-config/config)
              init-pallet/with-init 
              hardening/with-hardening
              hosteurope/with-hosteurope
              jira/with-jira]
    )
  )
```

Comment: Should that be a set rather than an anonymous function as the 2nd arg? i.e. `#{meissa-jira-large}` instead of `#(meissa-jira-large)`? Also, can you show what `jira-group` is?

Comment: Hi your completely right. The correct spec is `{jira-group #{meissa-jira-large}}`. But unfortunately your suggestion generates the error mentioned above (... I just wrote it wrong in the question ...).

Answer (score 0):

```
(api/lift 
    {:groups #{jira-group} :targets #{meissa-jira-large}}
    :user my-user
    :compute provider
    :phase [:init])
```

works :-)